# How to get only the visible message count for an azure queue

Tags: azure-queues

Looking through the documentation for the Azure Queue api here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/queue-service-rest-api

I see the get queue meta data method call will return me an approximate queue depth.  But this also includes the invisible messages in the queue. I'm not seeing anything I can specify to get only the visible message count in the queue.

Is there another api method I should be using to get that information?

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution to my own question. Performing a GET request https://{serviceNamespace}.servicebus.windows.net/{queuePath} will return MessageCount.